# how to remove space from arebic content using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have url that contains arebic language that does not allow in rss feed may be because arebic start with space or end with space how to remove space from arebic contains

used

```
var link = http://www.someurl.com/ محليات 0042 / # أخبار_ابزوق -..- «الصحة -80ار

link.split(" ").join("")
```

Tried this way does not work for me

does not work for me how to resolve this issue

Comment: Not a hundred percent sure, but may you can get rid of it using `link.replace(' ', '')` ?

Comment: The split code you have works for me and outputs `"http://www.someurl.com/محليات0042/#أخبار_ابزوق-..-«الصحة"`.

Comment: but when you translate it from google translate it gives you space